# ckeditor storing datas php

Tags: php, mysql

It's new for me to use richtext but a user has to be able to insert pictures or to change his text. So I'm using ckeditor but i've some trouble with it.
When a user write into the rich text he can write things using apostrophe and comas. 
I'll use an example. Let's imagine i want to write :

```
It's quite difficult to open a picture, a file  blablabla
```

The problem is that in the inserting query looks like that

```
Insert into tab (txt1,txt2) values ('value1','value2')
```

If the user uses comas or apostrophe the richtext cannot be correctly inserted. Moreover, I use `longtext` in my MySQL database to store the text.

My questions are :

- How to store the richtext written by the user
- What type should be the column in my MySQL database to correctly store the richtext to be able to give it back

The problem i have is

```
    Erreur SQL !INSERT INTO detail_article(ID,Problem,Num,URL,Solving,Description) VALUES(16,'Chrome : clearing datas',4,'','

    \r\nCHROME CACHE CLEARING :

    \r\n\r\n
   blablabala

    \r\n\r\n

   In the 'windows explorer', do the fallowing statment....blablabla


    \r\n','')
```

It's a sample of my text but i think the problem is caused by the quotes and the coma

Comment: Hello ! If the script does not work if the user uses commas and apostrophes, then does it mean you does not escape the richtext he did provide ? How do your script access the database ? Is it using PDO or something like that ? If not, have a look at this https://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.quote.php

Comment: I store the textarea into a var then i send it to mysql database with a `mysqli` statement

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must come from your PHP script which seems not to escape the pieces of data it send.

If it's not working with the richtext containing commas and apostrophes, then it's probably that the query send to your database isn't escape.

For example, if you have such content :

```
$value2 = "Catch',em all";
$value1 = "Hello boys";
```

And if you try to store it in database without escaping it, then the resulting SQL query will looks like :

```
INSERT INTO tab (value1, value2) VALUES ('Hello boys', 'Catch', em all);
```

which will be an incorrect SQL statement because of incorrect syntax.

If you use some escape method like PDO::quote(), your input will be inserted in a safe way that won't produce any error (syntax).

Make sure your script does escape the params you send with either PDO::quote() (https://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.quote.php) or either mysqli_real_escape_string (http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I just used `mysqli_real_escape_string` and it doesn't work either and my text is correctly escaped. The escape function did work but i still have the problem.

Thank you for answering though, i do appreciate

Comment: Could you print an exemple containing a error-generating input with the resulted escaped string and the final generated query ? Thanks in advance

Comment: If i give the richtext escaped back, are the /r and /n going to disappeared ? Or i have to use another function to translate the escaped text ?

Comment: Erreur SQL !INSERT INTO details(ID,Problem,Number,URL,Solving) VALUES(16,'Chrome : Not working and black screen',4,'','

\r\nCLEAR CHROME CACHE :

\r\n\r\n
Settings > confidentiality> Clear browsing data

\r\n\r\n')

Comment: I did not write everything because the text is  long

Comment: Could you add this to your original post so that everyone would be able to see it fully and with syntax color please ? :)